# hyperlink to open a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Is there any way to change a hyperlink / `<a href="#"></a>` tag into a datepicker? I dont want the whole date field as it will work as they click on a date and it goes to a certain part of the page (where a post with that date is situated).

I have tried this:

```
<li class="calendar"><a href="#"><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
```

and then the jquery:

```
$('calendar').datepicker();
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: Well first off try $('.calendar').datepicker(); instead.  Thought I have a feeling there's a lot more going wrong here.

Comment: That won't work either, but as you say to match selector by class you need to prepend a ".". If your'e matching an Id you prepend "#" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement your functionality you can follow next statements:

1. Stick to some date format (for example, **2014-01-20**).
2. Use `datepicker` on hidden field with specified format (to make it
   like **2014-01-20** you should provide following `"yy-mm-dd"`):

   `$("#inputDate").datepicker({
       dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"  /*...*/ }`
3. Mark html elements ("certain parts of page"), which you want be
   accessible by date, with `data-date="yyyy-mm-dd"` (actual dates you need).
   Also provide some `class` to these elements to identify them (I have
   used `"post"`):

   ```
   <div class="post" data-date="2014-01-20">Posted on 2014-01-20</div>
   <div class="post" data-date="2014-01-21">Posted on 2014-01-21</div>
   <div class="post" data-date="2014-01-22">Posted on 2014-01-22</div>
   ```
4. Add some anchor `<a id="openDatepicker">Go to</a>` and show datepicker on this anchor click:

   ```
   $(document).on("click", "#openDatepicker", function (e) {
       $("#inputDate").datepicker("show");
       return false;
   });
   ```
5. Provide `onSelect` handler for datepicker. Inside it you are able to
   access the selected date. Find elements, marked with
   `"data-date=SELECTED_VALUE"` and do anything you want with these
   elements (for example, scroll to it and mark with some `class`):

   ```
   $("#inputDate").datepicker({
       /*...*/
       onSelect: function () {
           //get selected date
           var date = $('#inputDate').val();

           //find all "posts"
           var posts = $(".post");

           //unmark all "posts"
           posts.removeClass("selected");

           var matchedPost = posts.filter("[data-date='" + date + "']");

           if(matchedPost.length > 0) {
              //mark matched post
              matchedPost.addClass("selected");

              //and scroll to it
              $("body").animate({scrollTop: matchedPost.offset().top}, 800);
           } else {
              alert("Nothing on this date");
           }
   });
   ```

## Full demo is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/2yDHb/7/).

Comment: This works great with getting the datepicker to display, but I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Comment: It happens in case when none of posts marked with selected date. I have edited my answer and demo. Only **2014-01-20**, **2014-01-21** and **2014-01-22** dates will cause scrolling and selecting of a `div`. Add more `div`s with different `data-date` attribute if you need

Comment: No, I keep getting this error - `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'matchedPost.offset().top')` regardless of what date it is, or format

Comment: Are you using my demo?

Comment: yes I am, the exact code. but when I try it in localhost, it gives me that error

Comment: I took everything out and put it back in and it worked. Obviously I missed something! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this
http://jsfiddle.net/c5jC8/

html:

```
<li class="calendar"><a href="#"><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
<div id="datepicker" class=hidden></div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$(".calendar a").click(function(){
   $("#datepicker").toggle();
});
```

css:

```
.hidden{
   display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could attach the datepicker to a hidden input.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="open">Open</a><br />
<input type="hidden" id="date" />
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        var date = $('#date').val();
        // Do something with the value here.
    }
});
$('#open').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#date').datepicker('show');
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uvwLj/)

Comment: This worked for me, though I added the `disabled` attribute to the hidden input.

Answer (score -1):

> The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field. Focus on the
>   input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a
>   small overlay. Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the
>   input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is
>   shown as the input's value.

[jQuery UI - Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Reading in the web you can see that the datepicker can only be tied to an input field

Comment: That is wrong... You can tie it to a div as well... se my fiddle/answer!

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I think that they could change the information on their web :D